# Power mocking private method which invokes another private methods

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermock

I am trying to mock a private method as below. However, at line # 4 , JUnit is invoking the relevant validateLanguage method and not returning the mocked value due to an exception thrown from the private method validateLanguage as it calls another methods. My understanding was JUnit using PowerMock should skip the invocation of actual implementation of validateLanguage. Can someone clarify ?

```
    public void validateCAR_SourceValidation_Success() throws Exception{

1.          long partyId=21;

2.          ErrorMessage errorMessage =Mockito.mock(ErrorMessage.class);
            CARValidationInfoVO carValidationInfo = Mockito.mock(CARValidationInfoVO.class);

3.          BibliographicRecordProcDAO bibRecProcDao=PowerMockito.spy(new BibliographicRecordProcDAO());

4.          PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(bibRecProcDao,"validateLanguage",carValidationInfo,true,errorMessage);
5.          bibRecProcDao.validateCARFile(carValidationInfo, partyId);
    }



private boolean validateLanguage(CARValidationInfoVO carValidationInfo, boolean successFlag, ErrorMessage errorMessage) throws OPSBankServiceDAOException {
        boolean tempFlag;
         boolean tmpFlag =  successFlag;
        if (Utility.isNotEmpty(carValidationInfo.getLanguageList())
                && carValidationInfo.getLanguageList().iterator().hasNext()) {
            tempFlag = validateLanguages(carValidationInfo.getLanguageList(),
                    errorMessage);
            tmpFlag = tmpFlag && tempFlag;
        }
        return tmpFlag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your method call is being mocked? Does your expected CARValidationInfoVO object equal the object is passed to the real method call?